# No cursor movement when under Pointer Lock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, three.js

I use [Pointer Lock](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-pointerlock-20120529/) for capturing the cursor in a game I'm developing in JavaScript with three.js. I've done my basic Googling, but I can't seem to find why, on Chrome OS, the cursor doesn't seem to move. If you look at http://scheib.github.io/HTMLMisc/PointerLockAndFullscreen.html Pointer Locking is working just fine and there's even a nice "cursor" to go along with the movement!

JavaScript Console output (The logging is me):
[image]

I "fabricate" the movementX/Y with

```
if (evt.movementX === undefined) {
    evt.movementX = evt.screenX - lastx;
    evt.movementY = evt.screenY - lasty;
    lastx = evt.screenX;
    lasty = evt.screenY;
}
```

In case you're wondering, I'm just setting up basic graphics.
[image: Such basic. Much wow.]

Answer (score 1):

The cursor is not moving because you have "lock" it. But `evt.movementX` and `evt.movementY` gives you the direction of the movement.

You have to update the position or direction of your camera  and render the result to make it feel like it moves.

Answer (score 0):

Under pointer lock, only the movementX and movementY properties are available. All other "ordinary" position co-ordinates are deliberately set to zero.

In pointer lock mode, it is perceived that there is no cursor, only mouse movement, so there's no (screenX,screenY) for a cursor which does not exist, nor is there an (offsetX,offsetY) for the same reason.

Only (movementX,movementY) by design.